# Arrays and Array amounts in Java

Tags: java, arrays

How can you initialize two random amounts to an array in Java? I tried this, but it already gave me a tonne of errors. In this program, I wanted to initialize 2 amounts to the array, the account balance, and the account number.

```
public class Bank {

    public static void main (String args []){

        int [] account;
        account = new int [100];

        for(int c = 1; c < 100; c++){
            int account[c] = {Math.random() * 1000  , Math.random() * 100};
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: tonne of errors? which errors?

Comment: was the tonnage split between compile and run time errors?

Comment: Apart from the real problem, I think you should really move those two fields in a class, and use it's object instead.

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You're declaring an array with 100 positions but you want to initialize 2 amounts? Do you want 2 ints per array position? Also avoid using arrays in Java.

Comment: How about going through some basic tutorials first? You are stumbling in the dark here.

Comment: Those are the errors genius
error: ']' expected
error: illegal start of expression
error: illegal start of expression
error: not a statement
error: ';' expected
error: not a statement
error: ';' expected
error: class, interface, or enum expected

Comment: That's not a ton of errors, it is actually just one, the first one, and the rest are its consequences.

Answer (score 4):

Your array is single-dimension, therefore you cannot initiase an element of it to two values.  Further, you shouldn't declare the type of each element in the loop.  What you are looking for is a two-dimensional array - with the code like this:

```
public class Bank{
    public static void main (String args []){

        int [][] account;
        account = new int[100][];

        for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++){
            account[c] = new int[]{(int)(Math.random()*1000)  , (int)(Math.random()*100)};
        }

    }
}
```

Also note that the loop should start with 0, not 1 (Java arrays are 0-based). Finally, note the `(int)` cast - you need this to avoid *possible loss of precision* errors.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know - hence I specified the explicit conversion.

Comment: How do you display the amounts seperately then?

Comment: Oh, I see, I parsed your statement wrong. My browser doesn't render italics :-)

Comment: then how should it be?

Comment: @user2291293 Just as I specified.

Comment: example pls, so sry but im a real beginner

Comment: @user2291293 Examples of what?  The code in my answer compiles and runs as is without any errors.

Answer (score 2):

Your program with a few improvements:

- the first index of arrays in Java is `0` not `1`
- introduced `java.lang.Random` as it provides cleaner way of getting a new random value from the fixed range (`0` .. `1000`)

  ```
  public class Bank {
      public static void main (String args[]) {
          final Random rnd = new Random();
          final int [][] account = new int [100][2];

          for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++){
              account[c] = new int[]{ rnd.nextInt(1000)  , rnd.nextInt(1000)};
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Next up: teaching OP to make classes instead of arrays :-)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am a fan of learning in small steps :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
int account[c] = new int............
```

you are probably looking for

```
account[c] = new int............
```

Comment: That's just partial advice. He also needs a 2-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

First `account` is a duplicate variable, second you don't need the initializers.
The third problem is that `account[0]` won't get initialized. So the corrected version looks like this:

```
public static void main (String args []){

    int [] account;
    account = new int [100];

    for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++){
        account[c] = (int) (Math.random()*1000);
    }

}
```

or if you need an array of arrays you can do this:

```
int [][] account = new int [100][2];

for(int c = 0; c < 100; c++){
    account[c] = new int[]{ Math.random()*1000  , Math.random()*100};
}
```